# ~60 requests/hour to `compute.v1.BackendServicesService.Get` only returning 404s

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-iam

###### 2023-05-16: Update

Curiously, the project logs don't include **any** references to these method calls. I may be overly sinking logs to `/dev/null` but there are other references to `compute.googleapis.com/v1` but not to the [`backendServices.get`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/backendServices/get) method.

```bash
PROJECT=".."
FILTER='
log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity")
protoPayload.serviceName="compute.googleapis.com"
protoPayload.methodName=~"v1.compute"'

gcloud logging read "${FILTER}" \
--format="value(protoPayload.methodName)" \
--project=${PROJECT} \
| sort \
| uniq
```

```
v1.compute.addresses.insert
v1.compute.firewalls.insert
v1.compute.forwardingRules.insert
v1.compute.instanceGroups.addInstances
v1.compute.instanceGroups.insert
v1.compute.instances.insert
v1.compute.projects.setCommonInstanceMetadata
v1.compute.subnetworks.patch
v1.compute.subnetworks.setPrivateIpGoogleAccess
```

###### 2023-05-15: Update

Thanks to @john-hanley who clued me in on a way to identify the `MYSTERY` Service Account. Grep'ing the audit logs, found a few entries of the form:

```
logName: projects/ackal-230515/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity
protoPayload:
  ...
  request:
    '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.iam.v1.SetIamPolicyRequest
    policy:
      bindings:
      ...
      - members:
        - serviceAccountId:112852397007451968863
        role: roles/container.serviceAgent
```

And there's only one member in the Project's Policy binding that uses this role:

```bash
gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} \
--flatten="bindings[].members" \
--filter="bindings.role=\"roles/container.serviceAgent\""
```

Yields:

```
bindings:
  members: serviceAccount:service-{number}@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/container.serviceAgent
```

So, I know what Service Account is being used and I know it's related to Kubernetes Engine but I don't understand why this Service Account is making unnecessary method calls.

###### Original Question

I have been reviewing `serviceruntime.googleapis.com/api/request_count` for `consumed_api` in an effort to audit a Project's Service Accounts.

> Recently, I swapped a Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster's nodes' Service Account from the Default Compute Engine account to a User-managed account with role `roles/container.nodeServiceAccount` and I am trying to ensure that there are no failed method calls by this Service Account.

Among the non-200 response code results are ~60/hour calls to [`compute.v1.BackendServicesService.Get`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/backendServices/get). There are only 404s against this method.

Questions:

1. <strike>How can I determine the Unique ID for Google-managed Service Accounts?</strike>
2. <strike>What could be using this Service Account to make these calls?</strike>
3. Why is Kubernetes Engine using this Service Account to make thousands of unnecessary methods calls?

I'm using a myriad of Google Cloud services (Cloud Run, Kubernetes Engine, etc.) but no Load Balancers and the project does not contain any Backend services:

```bash
gcloud compute backend-services list \
--project=${PROJECT}
Listed 0 items.
```

The calls are all made by a Service Account that I'm unable to identify: `100678112478450061433`.

It's not the ID of one of the Project's Service Accounts:

```bash
PROJECT="..." # Project ID
MYSTERY="100678112478450061433"

gcloud iam service-accounts list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(uniqueId)" \
| grep ${MYSTERY}
```

And it's not the ID of an `describe`'able Service Account in the Project's IAM binding:

```bash
PROJECT="..." # Project ID
MYSTERY="100678112478450061433"

EMAILS=$(\
  gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} \
  --flatten="bindings[].members" \
  --filter="bindings.members~\"serviceAccount:*\"" \
  --format="value(bindings.members.split(sep=\":\").slice(1:))" \
  | uniq | sort)

for EMAIL in ${EMAILS}
do
  printf "%s: " ${EMAIL}
  ID=$(\
    gcloud iam service-accounts describe ${EMAIL} \
    --format="value(uniqueId)" \
    2>/dev/null)
  if [ -z "${ID}" ]
  then
    echo "Inaccessible"
    continue
  fi
  if [ "${ID}" = "${MYSTERY}" ]
  then
    echo "Found!"
    break
  else
    echo "No match"
  fi
done
```

I suspect it is one of the Google-managed Service Accounts, but I don't know how to find the Unique ID for these:

```
{NUMBER}@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
{NUMBER}@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
service-{NUMBER}@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com
service-{NUMBER}@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
service-{NUMBER}@containerregistry.iam.gserviceaccount.com
service-{NUMBER}@firebase-rules.iam.gserviceaccount.com
service-{NUMBER}@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
service-{NUMBER}@gcp-sa-artifactregistry.iam.gserviceaccount.com
service-{NUMBER}@gcp-sa-cloudbuild.iam.gserviceaccount.com
service-{NUMBER}@gcp-sa-cloudscheduler.iam.gserviceaccount.com
service-{NUMBER}@gcp-sa-firestore.iam.gserviceaccount.com
service-{NUMBER}@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com
service-{NUMBER}@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

If I can identify the Service Account, I'm closer to understanding the cause.

Comment: I am not aware of a method to `describe` Google managed service accounts. When I try, I get a 403 permission error for `iam.serviceAccounts.get`. The same for listing the service account keys. Try this: modify the IAM roles for one of the Google managed service accounts. Go to the audit log and look for an entry with `service-agent-manager@system.gserviceaccount.com`. That service account manages the roles that are granted to other Google-managed service accounts. It is visible only in audit logs.

Comment: Thanks @john-hanley. Yes, that's the error I get too when trying to describe them. It makese some sense that they're opaque but then they should 'decipherable'. I'll try your suggestion, thank you! Hope all's well with you.

Comment: I can see the IAM roles assigned to Google-managed service accounts in the web GUI console. I am not sure how that is done. I am very interested in following this problem.

Comment: I tried adding a role to one of the Google-manageds. The only entry I get in the audit logs is the `SetIamPolicy` method and that represents the Service Account using its email address (not ID). I was unable to find any entries for `service-agent-manager@system.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: After deleting the GKE cluster, the errors have ceased. So, that focuses my attention but I'm still unsure why .... Perhaps something anticipating the Ingress creating a Load Balancer? When I create a new Project tomorrow to deploy the app, I'll monitor when the errors begin (presumably with the creation of the GKE cluster).

Comment: @DazWilkin Is your issue resolved?if yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it.

Comment: @sai-chandra-gadde no, it's not (yet) resolved. It's almost certainly GKE that's causing it. I realized that my previous query eliminated `location` and, including `location` shows that the calls are split ~evenly between `us-central1` and `us-central2` (in which I don't deploy resources) but, I still don't know what Service Account this is and I don't understand why there are so many calls to `compute.v1.BackendServicesService.Get` and why they **all** 404.

Comment: ...well, I guess I know why they 404 (I don't have any Backends!). I don't understand what (Google-managed Service Account?) is trying to enumerate these resources in my Project.

Comment: @john-hanley so I confirmed the Service Account (`service-{number}@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com`) with `roles/container.serviceAgent`. Your approach was good. I think I just misapplied it. I searched the entire log space for the Account's unique ID and the only matching entries were bindings `members:[ serviceAccountId: {MYSTERY}], role: roles/container.serviceAgent`. There's only one Service Account in the project's Policy. So I know what but still don't understand why

Comment: @DazWilkin - I think you are seeing https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#implementation_details

Sadly, the check considers a 404 as success since it means the ingress controller has IAM permissions and expects that the backend does not exist.

If you are not using any Ingress resources, you could disable HTTP load balancing on the cluster and then I think this will disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `container-engine-robot` service account is used to manage the lifecycle of GCE resources (e.g. nodes, disks, load balancers) used by GKE.

I believe the backendServices.get call is coming from the Ingress controller which is periodically checking to make sure it has the proper IAM permissions to manage load balancer resources.

Looking at https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#implementation_details :

> The Ingress controller performs periodic checks of service account
> permissions by fetching a test resource from your Google Cloud
> project. You will see this as a GET of the (non-existent) global
> BackendService with the name
> k8s-ingress-svc-acct-permission-check-probe

I took a look at the implementation and apparently it expects to receive a 404 (as the resource should not exist) and considers that a successful check.