# Unknown API Keys and the `anonymous' Service Account

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, service-accounts, google-iam

In my attempt to uncover a mysterious Service Account and failing API calls (see: [~4000 requests/hour to `compute.v1.BackendServicesService.Get` only returning 404s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76232032)), I've uncovered another mystery:

1. Unknown API Keys being used
2. A Service Account with a Unique ID of `anonymous`

The Project has **no** API Keys configured.

Questions:

1. What are these API Keys and why are they being used?
2. What is the `anonymous` Service Account and why is it being used?

I'm using Google Managed Prometheus' Prometheus API and PromQL because I'm more familiar with it than MQL but hopefully the following queries are self-explanatory (using metrics from `serviceruntime.googleapis.com` with resource type `consumed_api`:

```bash
PROJECT="..."
MONITORING="https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v1"
ENDPOINT="${MONITORING}/projects/${PROJECT}/location/global/prometheus"

TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)

START=$(date +%s -d "3 hours ago")
END=$(date +%s)
```

And to list the API Keys that have been used in the last 3 hours (since the Project's creation):

```bash
MATCH="
serviceruntime_googleapis_com:api_request_count{
  monitored_resource=\"consumed_api\"
}"
START=$(date +%s -d "3 hours ago")
END=$(date +%s)

curl \
--silent \
--get \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
--data-urlencode "match[]=${MATCH}" \
--data-urlencode "start=${START}" \
--data-urlencode "end=${END}" \
${ENDPOINT}/api/v1/label/credential_id/values \
| jq -r '.|select(.status=="success")|.data[]|match("apikey:(.+)")|.captures[0].string')'
```

Yields:

```
AIza..1g
AIza...Nc
```

And to list the methods being used by these API Keys:

```bash
# With credentials beginning `apikey:` only
MATCH="
serviceruntime_googleapis_com:api_request_count{
  monitored_resource=\"consumed_api\",
  credential_id=~\"apikey:.+\"
}"

curl \
--silent \
--get \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
--data-urlencode "match[]=${MATCH}" \
--data-urlencode "start=${START}" \
--data-urlencode "end=${END}" \
${ENDPOINT}/api/v1/label/method/values \
| jq -r '.|select(.status=="success")|.data[]'
```

Yields:

```
google.cloud.functions.v2.FunctionService.ListFunctions
google.cloud.functions.v2.FunctionService.ListRuntimes
google.cloud.location.Locations.ListLocations
google.cloud.run.v1.Services.ListServices
google.cloud.scheduler.v1.CloudScheduler.ListJobs
google.cloud.scheduler.v1beta1.CloudScheduler.ListJobs
google.datastore.v1.Datastore.Lookup
google.firestore.admin.v1.FirestoreAdmin.GetDatabase
google.firestore.v1.Firestore.ListCollectionIds
google.longrunning.Operations.ListOperations
```

Firestore|Datastore uses on API Key; Cloud Run|Scheduler|Functions|Location(?) uses the other.

The `anonymous` Service Account is used to ~100 to `google.logging.v2.LoggingServiceV2.WriteLogEntries`